# My co-worker accesses MY email ALL the time, what can i do

Tags: email

I found out that my co-worker was in my personal work email.  She had emailed our HR department and was writing about personal information in my email!   I work at a Doctors' office in New Mexico and we are all at different computers daily.

I then emailed  the HR department and told them that she made a claim in my email account and that I  Always log out of my email.   I then went into the computer's history and saw where she had been going 'into my email for about a year!! .I don't even know how she is doing this but she is!

I never received a reply from HR ! So I assume that my supervisor stuck up for her and lied.

Also, My supervisor has changed my statistical scores for my bonus to make sure that I don't get one, when anyone can look at the numbers and legitimately see that they're not right.

My supervisor promotes a clique at work and every one tries to kiss her butt, but - I am the only person not doing it.

- I have put up with numerous untrue rumors being made up about me.
- I have put up with so much from my office that I am just sick of it!

I don't know what to do.   Honestly, the employee and supervisor are the heads of the clique and supervisor promotes it . I have had so much grief and feel harassed, should I quit? I've put up with so much the last 2 years. The doctors who work here have no idea what is really going on.

Does anyone have any advice? There is no union here to stick up for employees who need help.

Comment: It sounds like a serious security (IT) issue and maybe a legal issue, if a different employee can access your e-mail.  What country is this in?

Comment: @Brandin, or perhaps just a lesson in life not to assume that an ostensibly personal login or account, can only be accessed by that person. The "Horizon scandal" in the UK partly hinges on the fact that there were various ways in which the computer system could make records which were not commanded or caused by the person whose name appeared on them.

Comment: Can you please explain your situation more clearly? Is your email an address that assumes some level of privacy (for example Jane.Smith@practice.example.org) or more of a generic staff address (for example info@practice.example.org).  What is "going into my emails"? Do you suspect they *read* the email you send out? Or the email you receive? Or do they *write* emails from your address? If they do, do they impersonate you, by not signing or signing in your name? How did you find out they did this for over a year?

Comment: One of the lessons to be learned here is to not use a work email account (even a "personal work email") for your your own personal business. Even if this other co-worker is not entitled to access that account, your employer (almost) always is allowed, and my (often) delegate that to anyone in the company they choose (within reason).

Comment: What email system is your organization using? Have you gone to IT? Do you store your password on your browser? First, get to the bottom of this. In some organizations, it's possible for IT access your emails (even deleted emails). Does that other employee work for IT?

Comment: You have changed your password, right?

Comment: I have suspected that this other employee has been in my work email before,  and yes I chane my password ALL the time.  I'm not tech savvy,  but Idk how she's getting into it. I can see in the pc history where she's going into my email.

Comment: I don't store any password on browsers, I reported this incident to the HR woman who was emailing my account,  and reported the incident to IT and have not heard anything back from them.

Answer (score 8):

Addressing only the email question:

This is a question for IT, not HR. If the co-worker isn't supposed to have access to your mail, then they're violating policy, even if the access is because you left your password lying around or a logged-in machine unattended (obviously, don't do either, for exactly this reason). IT can check if and how it's really happening. Even IT itself shouldn't be accessing your mail without direct management instruction to do so.

If they *are* supposed to have access -- see that last sentence -- the only answer is that if you don't want the company reading a note you shouldn't put it through the company equipment. Use your own account, your own hardware (eg cell phone), and your own connection (*not* the company WiFi... Or at least if you must do so use your own VPN account so what pases through the company networks is encrypted).

And make it a question, not an accusation. Unless you have caught them with your mail folder open on their screen, you are guessing. Maybe whoever you sent that to forwarded it to your co-worker with a question. Maybe they aren't going by your email but by overhearing what you've said on the phone. It's entirely legitimate to ask about a security breach, but accusing without completely solid evidence can cause you no end of grief.

Comment: The employee emailed our HR department through my email!  I received HR emails returned to my email asking questions , and they had several conversations in MY email.   I actually emailed HR and woman said that she was emailing me back about the claim I sent in for the other employ. I then told the HR woman that the other employee was in my email without authorization.

Answer (score 1):

#### Stop going to HR with issues, talk to your boss

Your boss will never be interested in finding out about an issue from HR, and HR doesn't have operational authority anyway.  Never assume HR is there to "stick up for you;" HR works for management.

Based on your discussion with your boss, decide what to do.  Right now it's not even clear what your boss thinks of the situation.  If your boss doesn't resolve your situation, you go to the next level boss.

Comment: The author’s supervisor appears to be part of the problem

Comment: Yes, my supervisor is part of the problem,  she is in thick with this employee!  I can't turn to my supervisor for anything,  as I am not in their clique.  No One is supposed to have access to other employee's emails.  I just feel so frustrated,  this is a very TOXIC work environment!

Comment: Update:  HR department just emailed me back after a week of not hearing anything,  and said that I had to go to our compliance department and make a claim with them.  I left that email up in inbox, so I know that the other employee will see it, as I believe that she is still going through my email daily.  I don't know if I should report this to compliance dwpt.  I'm afraid that I will have retribution from my snake supervisor.

Comment: Make up your mind. Do something, or don't do something. We can't tell you which.

Comment: The supervisor is part of the problem,  there no way I could go to her, she would just cover it all up .